# Import-module : The script failed due to call depth overflow

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

Working on a PowerShell module and noticed I'm having an issue when attempting to import it, no matter how

```
import-Module -Name ".\0.0.1\PSSymantecSEPM.psd1" -Force
An error occurred while running the REPL loop:
System.Management.Automation.ScriptCallDepthException: The script failed due to call depth overflow.
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke[T](IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Services.PowerShell.Utility.PowerShellExtensions.InvokeAndClear[TResult](PowerShell pwsh, PSInvocationSettings invocationSettings) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\PowerShellEditorServices\Services\PowerShell\Utility\PowerShellExtensions.cs:line 76
```

After investigation, understood it's linked to recursion depth limit issue well described in a [VSCode issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/3962), but in my case it's not VSCode specific as I can reproduce without the integrated terminal

I assume now it's linked to my module directly, or manifest that somehow reaches this depth limit.

Anyone can point me to where/how I could fix this for this module ? Prepared some easy steps to reproduce via my personal project repo and specific branch I created to investigate this

```
# Closing repo
PS C:\Temp\test> git clone https://github.com/Douda/PSSymantecSEPM/
PS C:\Temp\test> cd .\PSSymantecSEPM\
# Switch to branch with issue
PS C:\Temp\test\PSSymantecSEPM> git checkout ScriptCallDepthException
Switched to a new branch 'ScriptCallDepthException'
branch 'ScriptCallDepthException' set up to track 'origin/ScriptCallDepthException'.
# attempting to import the module
PS C:\Temp\test\PSSymantecSEPM> Import-Module .\Output\PSSymantecSEPM\0.0.1\PSSymantecSEPM.psd1 -Force

The script failed due to call depth overflow.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CallDepthOverflow
```

Tried with PS 5.1 & PS 7.4.0, same issue

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.4.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.4.0
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

I may also note, I am using [ModuleBuilder](https://github.com/PoshCode/ModuleBuilder) to generate my module (and maintain versioning) but not sure it's linked

Thanks

Comment: You're asking to debug 6239 lines of code in your `.psm1` to find which of the functions is using recursion and then understanding why said function is causing an infinite loop ?

Comment: Not at all, You just answered one of my questions that I actually didn't put above. A specific function part of the module can do that ?

Comment: If the config file isn't found `Initialize-SEPMConfiguration` will call `Reset-SEPMConfiguration` which then calls `Initialize-SEPMConfiguration` which then calls `Reset-SEPMConfiguration`... you get the point :) Remove that cyclic path and you should be good

Comment: the issue is `Initialize-SepmConfiguration` calling `Reset-SEPMConfiguration` which then is calling again `Initialize-SepmConfiguration` causing an infinite loop.

Comment: I feel so silly now. I didn't mean to ask for debugging, I genuinely believed there was a potential issue with my manifest, not the code itself as I didn't know it would be actually running on the import-module.

Comment: May I ask how you managed to spot this so quickly ? Any tools or best practices I'm missing ?

Comment: @Douda Parsed the file with [`[Parser]::ParseFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser.parsefile?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0), then listed all statements at the root of the script - there was only one command invocation, so that narrowed it down pretty quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is because of a cyclic relationship between `Initialize-SEPMConfiguration` and `Reset-SEPMConfiguration`.

`Initialize-SEPMConfiguration` is invoked on module execution/import, fails to find the expected configuration values in a (possibly non-existing) configuration file, and calls `Reset-SEPMConfiguration`.

`Reset-SEPMConfiguration` appears to remove the config file (which possibly isn't even there), after which it calls `Initialize-SEPMConfiguration`, thus creating a call cycle that eventually exceeds your callstack's capacity.

Remove the call back to `Initialize-SEPMConfiguration` from `Reset-SEPMConfiguration` and you'll be fine - my recommendation would be to implement some bounded retry-logic inside `Initialize-SEPMConfiguration` instead of recursing.